# Is there a plugin like Zenbu for the CP members admin section?

Tags: members, control-panel, admin

We have a client that wants to see member custom fields when looking at the control panel member list (including the "activate pending members" screen).

Is there a plugin similar to [Zenbu](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu) except for the members section? Are there any other ways to display custom member fields on the member list page?

Note we are **not** using Zoo Visitor or Profile:Edit on this site and would prefer not to add these to an already complicated site unless we really need to.

Comment: I see that you don't want to add Zoo Visitor unless necessary, but I don't think there is another option. I would double check first that vistor and zenbu work together in the way you want should you go that route.

Comment: I can also wholeheartedly recommend the zoo visitor / zenbu combination. you can even export users via csv if you choose hokoku. it's a bliss! also editing members is great! nothing compared to users or profile:edit. and you see members that need to be activated as well. you can filter for member groups. show individual fields etc... and all within the edit screen. nothing beat's that! and it's super easy to setup!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be nice. I haven't seen one.

I often create a frontend admin area to list out members how I want them, and create frontend forms to edit their details.

Sorry, it's the long way. However, it is useful if there are editors that have no need to login into the CP, but need to control the membership side of things.